# How can I move quantity box after product title in magento 2.3?

Tags: product, addtocart, magento2.3.2, quantity, product-detail-page

I want to move **quantity box** after product title without moving **add to cart** button on product detailed page.

I have tried to move quantity box using jQuery but after that always single quantity (Default) added in the cart

Can anyone help me to move it?

Comment: where do you want to implement ? On product page or cart page or minicart ?

Comment: I want to implement on product page